# Running a patched binary within IDA Free

Tags: ida

I am using IDA Free for malware analysis and I wanted to patch a binary I am looking at. I applied the patch by using the patch menu, which modifies the DATABASE representation of the executable.

When I go to run the executable via *Debugger -> Run*, it warns me that the database has been patched and there may be inconsistencies. However, when it finally runs it runs the original executable without patched code!

Is there a way to tell IDA to run the patched code? Or, since it's only patched in the database, my only choice is to export a *DIF* file and patch it manually to confirm it works?

Comment: Did you "Apply patches to input file"?

Comment: @sudhackar IDA Free is only IDA 5.0, I dont have that option.

Comment: Then you can manually patch the file using a hex editor. I don't know of other options in IDA free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDA Free doesn't support the *"Apply patches to input file..."* feature. Hence, you'll have to do this the old way. I'll expand my answer and will go over things you already know so others (e.g coming from search engines) can benefit from a whole complete answer.

### Edit the configuration file

The first thing you have to do is to modify an IDA GUI configuration file named *idagui.cfg*. You should be able to find the file at *"IDA Free\cfg\idagui.cfg"*. Locate the file and change *"DISPLAY_PATCH_SUBMENU"* form *"NO"* to *"YES"*.

After that, start IDA Free and you'll see a fresh new sub-menu called *"Patch program"*.

### Patching

You should be able to use this sub-menu to edit the program. It's pretty intuitive, just put your cursor wherever you want to make a change, and choose the appropriate option from the sub-menu.

***Notice*** that every patch you do is only affected on the IDB, the IDA Database. Thus, the binary on disk won't be affected and when you'll try to debug/execute it you will not see your patches.

### Exporting a .DIF file

When you finish with all your patches, it's time to apply them to the binary on disk. To do this, you'll first have to produce a *.DIF* file that will contain a list of the changes you've made.

To produce this file go to *File -> Produce File -> Create DIF file..."*.

### Applying the changes to the binary

You can use [this](https://stalkr.net/files/ida/idadif.py) *Python* script by *stalker* to apply the changes. Use it like this:

```
$ idadif.py <original_binary> <IDA_DIF_file.dif> [revert]
```

**Alternatives:**
*Note that I didn't test these alternatives and I'm pretty sure that some of them will not work with IDA Free*

- [ida_patcher.c](http://www.idabook.com/chapter14/ida_patcher.c)
- [pe_write.idc](https://github.com/nihilus/IDA-IDC-Scripts/blob/master/PE-scripts/pe_write.idc)
- [IDA Patcher plugin](https://github.com/iphelix/ida-patcher)
- [IDA DIF Patch](https://github.com/grepwood/ida-dif-patch)

Comment: Yes I am well aware of this. Maybe I wasn't clear in my question. I want to run the patched binary to test it. Does IDA not run from the database? I don't want to export a dif without knowing it works.

Comment: No it can't. Just backup the original file and then apply the patches to either of them using one of the methods above.